# Parameter from <a href> tag not recieved in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying to show details of a employee by clicking name.

The jsp code to show the Employees list is given Its showing the details with a link. But cliking the link shows 404 Error

**Students.jsp**

```
<c:if test="${not empty objects}">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">



        <tr>
            <td><b>ID</b></td>
            <td><b>Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Age</b></td>
            <td><b>Date of Joining</b></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="o" items="${objects}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${o.id}" /></td>
                <td>
                <a
                    href="<c:url value="result.jsp">   

                            <c:param name="studId" value="${o.id}"/>   
                        </c:url>   
                    "><c:out value="${o.name}"/></a>
                </td>
                <td><c:out value="${o.age}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${o.doj}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>

    </table>
</c:if>
```

and server code i write for recieving request is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/result", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView student(@RequestParam("studId") int studId, ModelMap model)
{

    Student student=studentService.getStudent(studId);

    model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
    model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
    model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

    return new ModelAndView("result", model) ;
}
```

I've a result.jsp to show the details of the clicked employee. 
But it shows 404 error. Please advise what i'm doing is wrong

Comment: Your url is wrong. It shouldn't be `result.jsp` but `result` and should probably be prefixed with `/`. So try `/result`.

Comment: @M.Deinum And to make things safe, make it: ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/result

Comment: That should already be handled by the `<c:url />`.

Comment: Thanks it works. But i tried before with same but not working. Anyway now its working . Thanks for immediate response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 indicates it cannot find your "result" view.

Ensure you have correctly configured your view resolver.

If you have trouble identifying it still please post your code for view resolver configuration please and I'll help further.

Comment: Glad to help, please accept the answer so this question can be closed :)